# What port is used by SQL Server to write backups to a remote server?

Tags: sql-server, remote, backup

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard instance in a "DMZ", so that it can be client-facing. I am trying to have it write its backups to a central location that is within the network. The engineers suggest that they can open a port for me. Hence the question: What port is used by SQL Server to write backups to a remote server?

Comment: It will use the port that is assigned. By default it is 1433 (which is not a good practice to use due to security). Also, take the backup locally and then use ROBOCOPY or powershell to move the backups to a remote server. Dont try to write directly to a remote server as a n/w glitch will corrupt your backup.

Comment: @Kin "write backups to a remote server" would not occur over 1433. I'd of thought we were talking about [SMB ports](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block)?

Comment: @MarkStorey-Smith Yes, should have made it clear in my comment. It is the port on which sql server will listen the incoming client requests.

Comment: are you able to copy backup done locally to your network share ?

Answer (score 6):

Remote file access occurs over [SMB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block). Remote backups are just another form of remote file access. See [File and Sharing Protocol Stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd303117.aspx).

If you use SMB over TCP directly (ie. disable NetBIOS) then the port used is 445, both UDP and TCP. If you use NetBIOS then it requires 137 both UDP and TCP, 138 UDP and 139 TCP. See [Directly Hosting SMB over TCP/IP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/204279):

> NetBIOS over TCP traditionally uses the following ports:
>
> ```
> nbname            137/UDP
> nbname            137/TCP
> nbdatagram        138/UDP
> nbsession         139/TCP
> ```
>
> Direct hosted "NetBIOS-less" SMB traffic uses port 445 (TCP and UDP).

Answer (score 2):

I am doing remote backup by backing-up locally and then copying the bak files to remote storage file share.

I do not think it is much different if to backup directly.
Anyway I've checked it with WireShark:

[image]

having shown that TCP port 445 was used. Though, depending on Windows version (it was not even clear if your backup will be stored on a device under Windows), TCP port 139 could have been used or whatever the backup application/device/OS is configured to use.

Another question is that a port as such is not sufficient for giving access since it is being "opened" in context of ports, protocols, applications/programs, accounts.